# PHP exec() function windows 7 IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to run an a command line util using exec() but it doesnt return anything. I have read on php.net that the permissions on cmd.exe need to be set to allow the iis user to run it. I have not been able to do this using any method I can think of. cacls icacls and the standard security screen dont work. I am logging the output to a mysql database.

my code looks like this:

```
$Ret = array();
$err = "";
exec("dir", $Ret, $err);
```

in the db I get array for $Ret

Either something is wrong with the command, I doubt it, or I need to set the permissions somehow.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by `in the db I get array for $Ret`?  Are you converting it to a string?  Have you tried, for instance, `print_r($Ret)` to screen and see if it's still empty?

Comment: What version of PHP? 5.2, 5.3 or 5.4?

Comment: if I use var_dump($Ret); it shows an array with the output in it. I mean that in the field in the database it shows the text array instead of the output in a similar form to if I use var_dump(). Maybe i need to convert to a string? I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
exec("dir", $Ret, $err);
```

to:

```
$r = exec("dir", $Ret, $err);
echo $r;
```

You need to capture the return value of `exec` into a variable then render that.

Or try running this:

```
<?php
$a = array();
$e = "";

echo "exec'ing<br/>";
$r = exec("dir", $a, $e);

echo "var_dumping<br/>";

var_dump($a);

echo "=====================\n";

var_dump($e);

echo "=====================\n";

var_dump($r);

?>
```

If you're running this in a browser with xdebug turned off then you might need to view-source to see the results.

Comment: what if I dont want to echo the output I just want to save to a database? I cant get that to work. Not the database part but getting the output of the command to save. I tried creating a field for each variable like this $cmd = exec("dir", $Ret, $err); and I am storing $cmd $Ret and $err in separate columns. I get a blank field for $cmd and array in $Ret and blank $err. My guess is that $cmd doesnt actually execute and that is why but how else can I get it to run?

Comment: @JohnS Did you run the script I provided above? If so can you paste the output (you may need to do view source if running in a browser) into your question.